# Working with web user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a web user control which consists of a RadGrid and a SqlDataSource, which looks like this (at least part)

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ProductionMatching.ascx.vb" Inherits="ProductionMatching" %>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" DataSourceID="SqlNBTA" runat="server" GridLines="None"
    AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0">
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AlwaysVisible="True" Position="TopAndBottom">
    </PagerStyle>
    <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
    </HeaderContextMenu>
    <MasterTableView ShowHeader="false" TableLayout="Fixed" PageSize="250" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="True"
        PagerStyle-Position="TopAndBottom" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%--<asp:Panel ID="ItemContainer" runat="server">--%>
            <table width="100%" class="table-NoBorder">
                <tr class="tblHeader" bgcolor="#617E97">
                    <td width="50">
                        <b>Date</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="35">
                        <b>Match</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100">
                        <b>City</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="250">
                        <b>Hotel</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="250">
                        <b>Address</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100">
                        <b>Phone</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100">
                        <b>Account</b>
                    </td>
...
</RadGrid>
```

Then the SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlNotMatched" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProlodgicConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_ds_ProdGroupMatch" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DataSourceMode="DataSet" OnSelecting="SqlNotMatched_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ConfidenceLvl" DefaultValue="50" ControlID="MatchConfidence" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="FileID" DefaultValue="NULL" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" ControlID="FileID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ProdGrpID" ControlID="ProdGroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="SID" SessionField="SID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now is where I run into problems, the 3 select command parameters are 3 controls on the parent page (not in the UC itself), so how can I get the values from those 3 controls to my SqlDataSource in the control?

@Sam Not sure what you're asking but here's is how I load my user control (it's based on the selected index of a RadioButtonList)

```
Dim uc = LoadControl("~/ProductionMatching.ascx")l
Placeholder1.Controls.Clear()
Placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Comment: Did you try exposing them as public properties in your parent page then using those properties in your parameters?

Comment: @Sam no I havent, got any examples on how I would accomplish this? I've not worked with many user controls like this.

Comment: First show me how you use your user controls in your parent page.

Comment: I think it might not be because the control parameter would be scoped to the current naming container, IE the user control.

Comment: @Sam I think I provided (in the original post) what you're looking for.